# LWC doesn´t show Account records

Tags: lightning-web-components

Using the developer tools in Chrome, I noticed that the records are pulled correctly, but they are not shown in the LWC.

**MyController.cls**

[image]

**MyComponent.js**

[image]

**MyComponent.html**

[image]

**But this is how it looks..**

[image]

**However, the browser's console shows the records:**

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My doubt is: why the account records are not shown in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not assigning the data to **allAccounts** for each variable.

Current Js code:

```
@wire (getAccounts) wiredAccounts({data,error}){
      if (data) {
      console.log(data); 
      } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      }
 }
```

}

Need to modify Js as like below:

```
   @wire (getAccounts) wiredAccounts({data,error}){
    if (data) {
      this.allAccounts = data;
      console.log(data); 
      } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      }
 }
```

}

Comment: The solution worked after applying this change and declaring the variable allAccounts, thank you!!